# Riddle: A low-power car mover

Tags: lateral-thinking

(This will probably be an easy one...)

> What can accelerate a car fairly quickly, using only 10 watts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might also be Mr. Rasmussen,

> who founded the factory making the [**DKW**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKW) cars and motorcycles.

They were accelerating pretty quickly (by that time's standards anyway), and although they certainly used more than 10 watts of power,

> at the time (well before the 1960s when "da" became the standardised symbol for the prefix "[deca-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deca-)"), the abbreviation for "ten watts" would have been **dkW**.

EDIT: Oh, I may have figured out OP's original idea. Is it maybe

> **Traffic lights**? The green one (and also the yellow one immediately before the red) tends to cause a lot of car acceleration. According to one source I found, the modern traffic signals use LEDs with a combined power of 10W to 25W.

Comment: Yes, it's the EDIT answer.

Answer (score 4):

Is it...

> your foot, pressing down on the gas pedal (which likely uses much less than 10 watts of mechanical power).

Comment: Not quite the answer I was thinking of...

Answer (score 1):

Answer

> Gravity. If you push a car off a cliff, it'll accelerate at 9.81 m/s^2, and that doesn't take any watts.

Comment: Hmm... Nice answer, but not what I was thinking of...

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot, and it's true too.

Comment: Given that acceleration is proportional to force, and work (imparted energy) equals force times the distance moved, there are quite a lot of watts at play in this scenario, actually.